# Advantages of "float:left;" without its disadvantages

Tags: html, css

I want to have the same result as this : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/faDkw/

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" >Hello</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
World!
```

CSS:

```
#foo
{
    background-color:red;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

But without all the `<br />`, because the height could change.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is `#foo` floated if you want to put content below it?

Comment: @Jon Not to specify a `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just use `display: inline-block` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS%3adisplay)), which unlike `float: left` does not put the div outside of the page flow.

HTML

```
<div id="foo" >Hello</div>
<br />
World!
```

CSS

```
#foo
{
    background-color:red;
    height:400px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faDkw/1/).

Comment: Does `float:left;` have behaviours `display:inline-block;` doesn't have?

Comment: @Mageek Yes. Given your example using float you might put several lines of text besides the `<div>` using float, whereas with `display: inline-block` you can just put a single line of text beside it with the next line starting below the box.

Comment: And in general? (Not specially in my example)

Comment: Helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: The spec has the gory details, but I'll just say that the float model is a completely different realm from inline elements.

Comment: @Mageek Essentially you can achieve the same with both: [inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/faDkw/6/) - [float](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/faDkw/5/)